# Perform Action When property changes - Umbraco Events v7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6

When a user saves a given doc type I want to check a property value, if it has changed from the original value I want to perform some action.

Any Ideas?

I know how to use the events, what I need help with is the syntax... heres what I mean.

```
void ContentService_Saving(IContentService sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<IContent> e)
{
    foreach (var myNode in e.SavedEntities.Where(x => x.HasProperty("propertyName")))
    { 
        //if (myNode.GetPropertyValue("propertyName").hasChanged)
// then
//bla bla bla

    }
}
```

Also is there a version of this method that is a single IContent object rather than a list, In previous versions was this not the case?

Comment: Have you tried anything? see this if it helps https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/application-startup and update question if you face any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for..................... why is there no documentation on this method :-/

```
void ContentService_Saving(IContentService sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<IContent> e) {

foreach (var myNode in e.SavedEntities.Where(x => x.HasProperty("myproperty")))
    {
                if (myNode.IsPropertyDirty("packageStatus"))
                {
                           //perform action
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want one of the following events:

- "Document_AfterSave"
- "Document_AfterPublish"

See the link below for a list and description of all Umbraco Document Events:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/Document-Events

Once you have the correct one, implement as per the tutorial on the link provided above by @Chaitanya Gadkari

Any issues. Update the post.

Regards